# Question marked off-topic, don't see why

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, closed-questions

[My question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/100676/16011) was closed as off-topic.

The help says (shortened):

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> If your question generally covers …
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
>
> … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

My question covers *Google docs* which definitively behaves like an application and so fits the description completely, so why is the question considered off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

The close reason used by the moderator who cast the binding vote was:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue could not be reproduced as of 9/8/2017.

[Google-docs shared link requires login to edit document](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100676/google-docs-shared-link-requires-login-to-edit-document#comment96952_100676)

The term "off topic" is used as a general catch all and perhaps should be replaced by "out of scope" (but I'm sure that will be cause it's own headaches). In this case it doesn't mean that the question was off topic in that it wasn't about a web application, it means that the question can't be answered as the problem no longer reproduces.

If it recurs, or you find a way to reliably reproduce the problem then edit that into the question which will push the question onto the [reopen review queue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/reopen) where it's reviewed and potentially reopened.

Comment: You are right, I missed that comment.